# uninstall oracle client in AIX machine

Tags: unix, aix

I am new to AIX and I want to uninstall oracle client in my AIX machine. I don't know where the oracle client installed and how to find the installation location and steps to uninstall the oracle client.

Please help on this

Comment: Try to `find` a file called `libclntsh.so` somewhere on your computer. Btw: why do you want to delete it? You could simply non-use it and forget about its existence.

Comment: machine is going to decommission for that deleting the softwares

Comment: Found libclnsth.so yet? If yes, you can have a guess what to remove (eg: `rm -rf /orabin/OraHome_1`)